# Can't update view through ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

The method is invoked in server side, the fields are updated in managed bean but the view doesn't update.

```
<h:panelGroup id="grupoPergunta" rendered="#{gameController.view.mostrarPergunta}">
    <h:outputLabel id="pergunta" readonly="true" value="#{gameController.view.pergunta.descricao}" />
    <h:selectOneRadio styleClass="centro" value="#{gameControllerView.repostaEscolhida}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r1.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r1.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r2.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r2.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r3.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r3.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r4.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r4.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
        </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>
<!-- span onclick="sortearDado();"> Girar dado</span-->
<a4j:commandButton value="Pergunta" action="#{gameController.buscarPergunta()}" onclick="sortearDado();" render="grupoPergunta pergunta"/>
```

I also tried using `<f:ajax>` but no effect.

Comment: Please rewrite your question using English language. Also, use `render="grupoPergunta" only and make sure your managed bean is at least `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad kkkkkkkkkk        I'm having trouble updating my view from an ajax request. The method is invoked on the server part, the variables of the bean are populated but the values ​​are not updated in my view.

Comment: my backbean is @ViewScoped, and already have used your suggestion and did not work before

Comment: Then provide the necessary elements in your view to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I put the most rerendered internally and used in the render , it managed to solve my problem

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="painelPergunta">
                        <h:outputLabel id="pergunta" readonly="true" value="#{gameController.view.pergunta.descricao}"  rendered="#{gameController.mostraPergunta}"/>
                        <h:selectOneRadio style="border:0px;" styleClass="centro" value="#{gameControllerView.repostaEscolhida}" rendered="#{gameController.mostraPergunta}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r1.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r1.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r2.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r2.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r3.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r3.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{gameController.view.r4.alternativa}" itemLabel="#{gameController.view.r4.descricao}"></f:selectItem>
                        </h:selectOneRadio>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>






<h:commandButton value="Pergunta2" onclick="sortearDado();">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click" render="painelPergunta" listener="#{gameController.buscarPergunta()}"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
```